# Is this sufficient condition for infinite number generation from a finite seed also a necessary one?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-set-theory, recreational-mathematics

Given an initial finite set of natural numbers (the seed). Use the following rule to add numbers to the set. If $a,b,a+b \in S \rightarrow ab \in S$. Where $S$ is the is set. For example take the initial seed $\{2,3,5\}$.

$2,3,5 \in S \rightarrow 6 \in S \quad$ So now the new set is $\{2,3,5,6\}$

$3,3,6 \in S \rightarrow 9 \in S \quad$ So now the new set is $\{2,3,5,6,9\}$

$3,6,9 \in S \rightarrow 18 \in S \quad$ So now the new set is $\{2,3,5,6,9,18\}$

$9,9,18 \in S \rightarrow 81 \in S \quad$ So now the new set is  $\{2,3,5,6,9,18,81\}$

This seven-element set ends the generation, no new numbers can be added.

Now let's look at a second example where the initial seed is $\{2,3,4,5\}$

$2,3,5 \in S \rightarrow 6 \in S \quad$ So now the new set is $\{2,3,4,5,6\}$

$2,4,6 \in S \rightarrow 8 \in S \quad$ So now the new set is $\{2,3,4,5,6,8\}$

There is enough at this point to show that the set will be infinite.

Let $x \in \Bbb{N}\space|\space x\gt 1$. If there is the pattern of elements $x,2x,3x,4x$ in $S$ then the rule will produce infinite numbers. (In this example we have $2,4,6,8$.)

$x,x,2x \in S \rightarrow x^2 \in S$

$x,2x,3x \in S \rightarrow 2x^2 \in S$

$x,3x,4x \in S \rightarrow 3x^2 \in S$

$2x,2x,4x \in S \rightarrow 4x^2 \in S$

This means the new set will now contain $x^2, 2x^2, 3x^2, 4x^2$. This is inductive.

This condition of having $x,2x,3x,4x$ in the set is sufficient to show that there is an infinite number of numbers that will be generated.

My question is this a necessary condition to produce an infinite set?
In other words does there exist a finite seed that can generate infinite sets without any subset (from the seed or generated sets) of the form ${x,2x,3x,4x}$?

(@Ingix showed that the previous version of the question wasn't explicit enough the new formulation was made because of his critique)

I want to address potential confusion about sets and cardinality to people in the future who are reading this problem. I had this confusion and so did one other person in the comments. When we are determining the size of a set (some finite size, or infinite) only the number of **unique** items gets counted. This subtle fact about sets is important to this problem because if we had the seed $\{0\}$. What we could do is $0,0,0 \in S \rightarrow 0 \in S$.  Then our new set is $\{0,0\}$. This new set is just an inefficient way of writing the same set we had previously because both sets have the same number of unique items. Adding another $0$ doesn't change any of the properties of the set including the size. So you cannot create a set with infinite size just from the seed $\{0\}$

Comment: Technically a set has exactly one element of each specific value.  If $a,b\in S$ and $a=b$ then the contribution that $a,b$ make to the cardinality of $S$ is one element.  A Vector may be defined as a list of not-necessarily-distinct numbers.

Comment: @abiessu huh, I always thought that the cardinality of a set was the number of objects contained within. That it didn't matter if you had copies of objects or not just count the number and that's the cardinality. After looking at a few sources, all of the ones I saw have the same definition of a set as you describe it. That the definition is the number of distinct objects

Comment: Note: if you consider $0$ as a natural number, then the set $\{0,2\}$ will generate an infinite set. Of course, if you consider $x=0$, then I guess $\{0\}$ would be a set of the required form, but the singleton set $\{0\}$ will not generate an infinite set.

Comment: Just adding a bit for what @abiessu has already stated, considere the set $S = \{2,2\}$. We can state that $2\in S$, and that's it. So this set has only one element.

Comment: @StevenCreech The last paragraph at the bottom of the post specifically addresses this!

Comment: @quantus14 I guess my point is that it doesn't matter whether or not we consider $0$ as a natural number since if we do, then any set containing zero will have $\{0\}=\{x,2x,3x,4x\}$ (with $x=0$), and will generate an infinite set (as long as there is an additional element $y\neq 0$, as $\{0,y\}$ will generate $y^{2^{2^{...^{2}}}}$.

Comment: @StevenCreech I said in the post that $x>1$ so $x \neq 0$. Also, the final paragraph in my post is basically saying that you cannot have copies of numbers in your set. You are saying that if our starting seed is $\{0\}$.  $\quad 0,0,0+0\in S$ then $0*0\in S$. Then the new set will be $\{0,0\}$. That is against the rules I have constructed. Once you have one instance of a number you can't put another one in the set

Comment: The cardinality of a set **is** the number of objects contained within. The expression $\{2,3,5,5,5,5,5\}$ defines a set with three elements: that same set is more efficiently expressed as $\{2,3,5\}$.

Comment: It's not unlike other notations. The expression $1+2$ defines a number which is equal to the number more efficiently expressed as $3$.

Comment: I can't believe I just wrote the equation $1+2=3$ in such a roundabout way...

Comment: @LeeMosher okay maybe my terminology isn't perfect so let me make an analogy. Let's say we have two bags. One bag contains $20$ marbles another bag contains a marble, a rubber bouncy ball, d20, and a jack. I **originally** thought that cardinality was defined as the total number of items regardless of duplicates. So one bag would have cardinality $20$ while the other has cardinality $4$. abiessu showed me that this isn't the case that cardinality is the number of unique items so the first bag has cardinality $1$ and the second bag has cardinality $4$

Comment: @LeeMosher I was making the arithmetic more explicit for a reason that I now realize was redundant and unnecessary. I have edited my post for greater efficiency

Comment: @quantus14 Not to belabor this too much (since I think your actual question is clear, and orthogonal to this), but I think the objection that people are raising is that you're confusing sets and multisets.  In the context of multisets, it makes sense to talk about repeated elements.  But in a set, membership is binary:  an element either is or is not in a set.  It's not meaningful for a set to "contain the same element twice".

Comment: @RaviFernando (1/2)The issue is that there is one thread of comments where I make two separate points that from an outsider looks like they are in conflict with one another. So it appears that I am more confused than I actually am. In my first version of this post (the unedited version) I said the following in my final paragraph: "One point that I want to make explicitly here is $S\subset N$ at all times. This avoids the issue of having a set like $\{2,3,5,5,5,5,5,5,...,5\}$. Where you could technically have an infinite set but not address the problem I'm trying to solve. "

Comment: @RaviFernando (2/2) This paragraph was when I was still operating on the multiset definition. Steven Creech was also operating under this definition. He didn't read my final paragraph so even under the definition of a multiset I had already addressed his concern which annoyed me. If you want to see my current understanding of **set** and cardinality read the final paragraph of the current post and the comment I made in this thread about the marble bag analogy. I understand it clearly now

Comment: Remark: this is a vague converse to the [Erdős–Szemerédi theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Szemer%C3%A9di_theorem).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick summary: *No*, the set generated by the seed $\{22, 66, 88, 198, 220, 264, 286, 352\}$ is infinite and does not contain $\{z, 2z, 3z, 4z\}$ as subset for any positive integer $z$.

---

Let's prove this is indeed the case. For any positive integer $x$, we will define the set $A(x):=\{1x, 3x, 4x, 9x, 10x, 12x, 13x, 16x\}$. The generative rule applied to this set gives us
$$\begin{array}{|r|r|r|r|}
\hline
a & b & a+b & a\times b \\
\hline
1x & 3x & 4x & 3x^2 \\
1x & 9x & 10x & 9x^2 \\
1x & 12x & 13x & 12x^2 \\
3x & 9x & 12x & 27x^2 \\
3x & 10x & 13x & 30x^2 \\
3x & 13x & 16x & 39x^2 \\
4x & 9x & 13x & 36x^2 \\
4x & 12x & 16x & 48x^2 \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

As it turns out, the rightmost column corresponds precisely to set $A(3x^2)$. Thus, if we start with the seed of the form $A(x)$ for any $x$, repeated applications of the generative rule will produce an infinite set. Moreover, if we start with $x_0$ large enough and define $A_n:=A(3^{2^n-1}x_0^{2^n})$ for non-negative integers $n$, this infinite set $S$ will be precisely of the form
$$S = \bigcup_{i=0}^\infty A_i$$

We will show that $x_0=22$ suffices and the corresponding set $S$ is indeed closed under the generative rule.

Since $3x^2 > 16x$ for $x\geq 6$, the greatest element of $A_i$ is always strictly smaller than the smallest element of $A_{i+1}$ and so any element belonging to $S$ is member of exactly one $A_i$.

Now, consider any two elements $a\leq b$ of $S$. If $b\in A_i = A(x)$ for some $x$, we have $b\leq 16x$ and the sum $a+b\leq 2\times 16x=32x$. However, $32x<3x^2$ for $x\geq 11$, so $a+b$ cannot belong to $A(y)$ for any $y>x$ and thus must belong to $A(x)$. On the other hand, if $a+b$ and $b$ both lie in $A(x)$, their difference (= $a$) cannot be smaller than $x$ and thus $a\in A(x)$ too. However, if $a$, $b$ and $a+b$ all belong to $A(x)$, then $a\times b\in A(3x^2) = A_{i+1}\subset S$.

Last but not least, we would like to show that the set $S$ does not contain a subset of the form $\{z,2z,3z,4z\}$ for any integer $z$. If $z\in A(x)$ for some $x$, we have $z\leq 16x$ so $4z\leq 4\times 16x=64x$ and $64x<3x^2$ for $x\geq 22$. Thus, all four elements $z, 2z, 3z, 4z$ must belong to the same $A(x)$ and it is trivial to check no such quadruplet exists in any $A(x)$.

---

Note that there is nothing special about this particular set $\{1,3,4,9,10,12,13,16\}$; we could have started with any set which avoids the $\{z,2z,3z,4z\}$ pattern and which gets mapped to (a multiple of) itself by the generative rule. Any such set can be scaled up sufficiently to make it work as a seed for an infinite set, while maintaining the pattern-avoidance property (e.g. multiplying all elements of such set by anything greater than its maximum element is certainly sufficient).

Comment: Wow! Well done! (+1)